# What is the proper data structure for bidirectional one-to-many mapping?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, hash

```
user_1 is in [group_1, group_2]
user_2 is in [group_2, group_3]

therefore,

group_1 has members [user_1]
group_2 has members [user_1, user_2]
group_3 has members [user_2]
```

The use case is many read, less write, find:

- groups the given user is in.
- members in given groups.

Is there any proper data structure for this with low memory footprint?

Comment: Isn't that rather a many to many relationship?

Comment: Yes in general. I say one-to-many is to emphasis use cases.

Comment: Missing underscores:: group_1, group_2, group_3 should be used consistently above.

Comment: thanks. it is revised.

Answer (score 1):

The Graph data structure could be a better option in solving this problem.

**Adjacency List Approach:**

Map the group number with the list of user number to which the users are associated.

> **Map<groupNumber,userList>**

Similar case with the other mapping.

Map the user number with the list of group number to which that user is associated.

> **Map<userNumber,groupList>**

Answer (score 1):

Here's some Python that creates a class of two mappings and how they are used.

```
# Initial input maps users to any iterable collection of groups e.g. a list.
u2g = {'user_1': ['group_1', 'group_2'], 
       'user_2': ['group_2', 'group_3'],
      }

class Bi_map():
    def __init__(self, u2g_in):
        # internal forward map of user to tuple of groups
        self.u2g = {user: tuple(groups)
                    for user, groups in u2g_in.items()}
        # Assemble reverse mapping of group to appendable list of users
        g2u = dict()
        for user, groups in u2g_in.items():
            for group in groups:
                if group in g2u:
                    g2u[group].append(user)
                else:
                    g2u[group] = [user]
        # internal reverse map of group to tuple of users
        self.g2u = {group: tuple(users) 
                    for group, users in g2u.items()}
                    
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Typical use
    bi_map = Bi_map(u2g)
    
    assert bi_map.u2g == {'user_1': ('group_1', 'group_2'), 
                          'user_2': ('group_2', 'group_3')}
    
    assert bi_map.g2u == {'group_1': ('user_1',),
                          'group_2': ('user_1', 'user_2'),
                          'group_3': ('user_2',)}
    
    print(bi_map.u2g['user_2'])     # outputs: ('group_2', 'group_3')
    print(bi_map.g2u['group_2'])    # outputs: ('user_1', 'user_2')
```

Now the above assumes you have an initial one way mapping; want to create the two way mapping; then read the generated maps from then on.

If you wanted to occasionally add nextra mappings then one modification would be to keep mapping of strings to lists of strings in the class and add methods to update them.